# How to remove CR from the output and list all 'real' video controller / graphics cards

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following code that saves the primary (and secondary graphics card if detected) to a variable and it seems to work just fine. However, when sending the output to a log file (file.txt) it seems to append a couple of spaces and a CR.

Can anyone advise how to strip out the spaces and the CR or (suggested edit by Compo) get all 'real' video controller / graphics cards and store them in separate variables (with no spaces and/or CR's at the end)?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f tokens^=* %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe PATH Win32_videocontroller GET description^|findstr [0-9]
')do echo/%%~a|find "NV" >nul && (set "_VGA1=%%~a") || set "_VGA2=%%~a" 
(for %%V in (vga1,vga2)do echo\!_%%~V!) >> file.txt &endlocal
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Why not do it like this instead? `@(For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_VideoController Get Description /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @Echo(%%G) 1>>"file.txt"`, It uses the same syntax/method as I've offered you [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69991599/how-to-get-gpu-name-and-add-to-a-variable-while-ignoring-dock#comment123735564_69991599).

Comment: Because I'm connected through a dock and do not wan the output to shows as:

`DisplayLink USB Device
DisplayLink USB Device
Intel(R) HD Graphics 530
DisplayLink USB Device
DisplayLink USB Device`

My goal is to get the onboard GPU and also any other card that may be connected.

EDIT: Sorry but when clicking Add comment it does not seem to allow line breaks or proper formatted code.

EDIT2: I only outputted to file.txt to show the spaces and CR but ideally I need this info as variables.

Comment: I know that Bri, that is not the point I was making! I'm talking about the syntax, which certainly does not introduce unnecessary carriage returns/line feeds etc. Your code and question does not ask about identifying all 'real' video controller / graphics cards and saving  each to an individual variable for later use, it simply prints the `Description` of each, one per line, to a file. If I'm not mistaken the example code I've provided above, does exactly that too!

Comment: It does and also prints unwanted items. I see what you suggested strips the CR but I honestly do not know enough to now go about filtering and removing the other non-needed items. I have updated the title and my question in an attempt to be clearer on my requirements.

Comment: I appreciate that, however, this site doesn't tell you how to code a task, and it doesn't code it for you. You have to research and write it yourself. Essentially that is what you are asking for, _(or links to on, or off, site resources)_. On site resources are available via the search box at the top of the page, and off site resource requests are off topic.

Comment: I already submitted the code I had thus far and simply asked if it was possible to remove the spaces and CR at the end of the output to which you advised a different way which although I appreciate did remove said spaces and CR; it also introduced a whole new level of work to then filter out the un-needed items. This is not what I originally asked for. Can you please advise how to remove the above from the output of my original code if you are able as I do not know how to do it and came here for assistance due to this.

Comment: To clarify,  If I had asked for the entire thing to be written for me then I would understand your comments but I didn't.

Comment: If you visit the link to your previous question, _(provided in my opening comment)_, I gave you the code you asked for to filter out the USB devices too, so You have both the filtering code and the method to do it without the unwanted 'empty' lines. What therefore is the problem?

Comment: Firstly, I apologize if my lack of understanding offends but I am still learning and as such do not fully understand how to remove white space and/or CR. I have just about managed to select where I want to begin and end within the output of **WMIC** by using ```~x,x%``` to set new variables. IE: ```set VAR2=%VAR1:~x,x%```. In this instance (consider it a learning curve), could you please explain how I remove the spaces and CR from the original code?